# Does DescribeSObjectResult's property "updateable" make sure that if it is false, it will not have any field which is updatable?

Tags: soap-api

Suppose Object "LiveChatTranscript" has updateable set as true.
Does it mean It will not allow its fields to be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it works the opposite of what you've written in your question. If it can be updated, it will be true. If it can't be updated, it will be false.

The same would apply to fields that have been tested for createable. If true, they can be created. If false, they cannot be created other than by the system.